# Finding the matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have a transformation, $T(p(x)) = p(x+1) - p(x) -p'(x)$ on $R[x]_3$ (polynomials of degree 3) and I want the matrix for T. No basis is specified, so I'm assuming the standard, what should I do and how should I think about the problem?

Also, the question asks for an explicit description of the kernel and image of T. I'm not really sure what that means, could you explain it please?

Comment: Does the subindex $3$ in $R[x]_3$ stand for polynomials of degree 3? If so, just write $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$, compute your expression and simplify.

Comment: @MisterRiemann How does this provide me with a matrix?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

In the standard basis, the column vectors are the coordinates of $T(1),\, T(x),\, T(x^2),\, T(x^3)$ (in that order).

Comment: Ah okay that makes complete sense now, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: How would I ascertain information about the kernel  and image from this matrix?

Comment: The image is generated by the column vectors (two of them are $0$), as for all matrices. As to the kernel, you have to solve the associated linear equations; only two of them are linearly independent, and they're quite easy to solve.

Comment: I got the Kernel to be the zero vector and the image to be the span of (1,0,0,0) and (0,3,0,0), does this seem correct?

Comment: For thr image, it is correct. For the kernel, you're wrong: the determinant of this matrix is $0$, so it's can't be injective. Anyway, the computations for the matrix show the first two vectors in the matrix belong to the kernel.